# New PayPal iOS SDK (beta) - Can't connect to sandbox

Tags: cocoa-touch, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've integrated the new PayPal iOS SDK into my app. Reference can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/index). The new SDK is really easy to set up and it allows you to work in 3 different environments 1.) PayPalEnvrionmentNoNetwork 2.) PayPalEnvironmentSandBox and 3) No environment meaning to go onto their live servers. Everything works for the NoNetwork Environment, obviously because it uses mock dummy data, not having to access any servers. When I try to switch to the SandBox environment, PayPal can't connect to the servers, I get the following error:

```
  We're Sorry
  There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers. [Cancel][Try Again]
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem on my side or theirs. The following is the configuration:

```
 #define kPayPalClientId @"AbRN_BAV7YMsvde9KUFPsbSC_72NA9swMcY-j0QZL629lXrjSc9CNwfFn8Ac"
 #define kPayPalReceiverEmail @"The email I use to login into PayPal"


- (IBAction)pay {
   PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
   payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"14.99"];
   payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
   payment.shortDescription = @"Testing.";

   if (!payment.processable) {
    // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
    // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
    // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
    // to handle that here.
   }

   // Any customer identifier that you have will work here. Do NOT use a device- or
   // hardware-based identifier.
   NSString *customerId = nil;

   // Set the environment:
   // - For live charges, use PayPalEnvironmentProduction (default).
   // - To use the PayPal sandbox, use PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
   // - For testing, use PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork.
   [PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:self.environment];

   PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:kPayPalClientId
                                                                                             receiverEmail:kPayPalReceiverEmail
                                                                                                   payerId:customerId
                                                                                                   payment:payment
                                                                                                  delegate:self]; 
   paymentViewController.hideCreditCardButton = NO;

   [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

---

**FIX: Finally I figured out the problem, you need to add this after the view loads. I didn't have this at all.**

```
  [PayPalPaymentViewController prepareForPaymentUsingClientId:kPayPalClientId];
```

---

Comment: I can't reproduce here. Are you on a simulator or a device? What iOS version? Also, FYI, the `client_id` is a public credential, so it is safe to share, if you want to. (It has to be -- nothing embedded in an app is ever secret.)

Comment: device, iOS 6.0. I've updated the client id.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could possibly be then.

Comment: Hmm...I just tried on an iPad, iOS 6, with your client_id. I do want to get this sorted out, so please bear with me. Does the live environment work for you? And just to sanity check, the device does have connectivity? :)

Comment: Really appreciate it trying to help me, yea there is good connectivity and no it doesn't work for live environment. So the client Id isn't working for you either?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the client_id for sandbox is different than the one for production/live.

Comment: I also notice that `kPayPalReceiverEmail` is not defined as a real email address. Have you tried setting it to that of your PayPal account?

Comment: @tomwhipple hi, yes in my code I have it set to the email address I log into paypal with, I've also tried the facilitator email they creat for test accounts. I am 100% sure my account is a US account, yet Im still getting this problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! It seems that you've found a bug, since `prepareForPaymentUsingClientId:` is not supposed to be required. (Though it will improve your user experience if you call it from your view controller's `viewDidAppear:`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my colleagues determined in the comments, the issue was a bug in the PayPal iOS SDK, not in your code. We've fixed the issue in [version 1.0.4](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/1.0.4) ([.tgz](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/archive/1.0.4.tar.gz)).

With the updated library, your code should now work as expected; the `prepareForPaymentUsingClientId:` call should always be optional (though still recommended).

Thanks again!

Comment: No prooblem at all, love the new sdk btw. Very slick.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same issue.

This is all because PayPals new SDK is only available in the US and I'm guessing your elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: If you go to PayPals developers website and create a US sandbox account this will work absolutely fine :-)

Comment: Yea I'm in the US, don't know if my account is US though, I'll see.

Comment: So yea, my account is a US account, I've even gone through and made a brand new paypal account and it's still not working. What do you normally set the customerId to?