# Unable to access PayPal Sandbox account in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I'm integrating PayPal ios SDK in my iOS app.
Its working fine with PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork environment as it uses dummy data, but its not working with PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.
I'm unable to use my sandbox account. With reference to following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556622/new-paypal-ios-sdk-beta-cant-connect-to-sandbox) i also created another US account but its not working for me. Also i tried another [version](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/1.0.4) SDK but it gives same error message "There was a problem communicating with the PayPal servers".

If someone has resolved this problem please help me.
Thanks in advance